# Option valuation in illiquid markets

Tags: option-pricing, commodities

In my problem I have a liquid underlying, whose derivatives are not quoted and therefore the option market is illiquid. For this reason I can't get the implied volatilities and calibrate my model in order to obtain the fair value of derivatives.

This is often the case in the commodities industry. How can I estimate the implied volatilities?

I just make a fictitious example to better explain:

- I am trading palm oil in Thailand, which is very liquid and is quoted in real time.
- I would like to buy and sell simple European Calls or Puts in order to hedge myself. However they are not quoted in the market, and I have to decide their fair price. How do I do?
- The futures are quoted.

Comment: I suppose in such a case you have to look at historical volatilties of the underlying.

Comment: Are you able to request a quote from the counterparty you would be dealing with?

Comment: @amdopt   Yes but how do they quote it in the first place?

Comment: @NSZ I assume it will be a similar process as one that you will have to use.  You will have to model IV or try to use HV like noob2 suggested.  You might as well ask for a quote and give yourself a baseline though.  You will have to request a quote anyway before placing an order...